# How do I select/unselect in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a list of trainers and I have to select and unselect them as a toggle button. Below is the code to do so but I don't know how to implement it correctly.

Action:

```
 const selectTrainer = (selected) => ({
    type: 'SELECT_TRAINER',
    payload: {
      
      selected: selected
    }
  });
```

Trainer:

```
function Trainer(props) {

  const [addBtnToggle, setBtnToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      
        {addBtnToggle ?  <button onClick={() => setBtnToggle(!addBtnToggle)}>Selected</button> : <button onClick={() => setBtnToggle(!addBtnToggle)}>Select</button> }
        {addBtnToggle && <Select />}
    </>
  );
}

export default Trainer;
```

Reducer:

```
import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid';
const initalState = [
  {
    id: uuid(),
    name: '',
    team: [],
    selected: false
  }
];

let copyState = null;
let index = 0;

const trainerReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  const {type, payload} = action
   
    case "SELECT_TRAINER":
      return state.map((trainer) => 
        trainer.id === payload.id ? trainer.selected = true : trainer
      );


    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default trainerReducer;
```

Select:

```
function Select() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const allTrainers = useSelector((state) => state.trainers);
    allTrainers.map(a => a.selected===true );
  
    const arr = []
    arr.push(props.data.name)
    console.log(result)
    dispatch(actions.selectTrainer());
    return null
}
export default Select;
```

How do I add a toggle to unselect a particular item and how do I unselect the already selected item when I want to select another item?

Comment: In your reducer, does ``SELECT_TRAINER`` work at all ?

Comment: How do I check that? sorry I am new to redux

Comment: I personaly use "Redux Devtools" to view the state at any given time in my browser tab. Else you can just console.log the state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using what I refer to as legacy reducers (*i.e. pre-redux-toolkit*) you need to apply the [Immutable Update Pattern](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns). The reducer function is correctly creating a shallow copy of the `state` array, but it also needs to shallow copy any nested state it is updating. In this case it should create a new "trainer" object reference with the copied/updated properties.

Example:

```
const initialState = [
  {
    id: uuid(),
    name: '',
    team: [],
    selected: false
  }
];

const trainerReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const {type, payload} = action
  
  switch(type) { 
    case "SELECT_TRAINER":
      return state.map((trainer) => // <-- shallow copy array
        trainer.id === payload.id
          ? {                 // <-- new object reference
              ...trainer,     // <-- shallow copy trainer properties
              selected: true, // <-- overwrite property with new value
            } 
          : trainer
      );

    ... other cases...

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

> How do I add a toggle to unselect a particular item and how do I
> unselect the already selected item when I want to select another item?

This sounds like you want only a single selected trainer. You can update the reducer case to also check if the current trainer object is selected and deselect it.

```
case "SELECT_TRAINER":
  return state.map((trainer) =>
    trainer.id === payload.id
      ? { ...trainer, selected: true } 
      : trainer.selected
        ? { ...trainer, selected: false }
        : trainer
    );
```

or more **DRY**

```
case "SELECT_TRAINER":
  return state.map((trainer) =>
    trainer.id === payload.id || trainer.selected
      ? { ...trainer, selected: trainer.id === payload.id } 
      : trainer
    );
```

You will need to dispatch a trainer's `id` with the action. For this I suggest moving the redux logic from the `Select` component into the `Trainer` component so it computes the selected trainer value and directly dispatches the `selectedTrainer` action with the current trainer's id.

```
function Trainer(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const allTrainers = useSelector((state) => state.trainers);
  const isSelected = allTrainers.some(trainer => trainer.selected);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => dispatch(actions.selectTrainer(props.id))}>
      {isSelected ? "Selected" : "Select"}
    </button>
  );
}
```

To avoid needing to shallow copy the trainers array it may make more sense to just store a selected trainer id as a separate chunk of state.

Example:

```
const initialState = {
  trainers: [
    {
      id: uuid(),
      name: '',
      team: [],
    }
  ],
  selected: null
};

const trainerReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const {type, payload} = action
  
  switch(type) { 
    case "SELECT_TRAINER":
      return {
        ...state,
        selected: state.selected === payload.id ? null : payload.id
      }

    ... other cases...

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

...

```
function Trainer(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const selected = useSelector((state) => state.trainers.selected);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => dispatch(actions.selectTrainer(props.id))}>
      {selected === props.id ? "Selected" : "Select"}
    </button>
  );
}
```